different behavior when using a temporary variable for no apparent reason
I'm compiling a program in C with gcc 11.4.0 on Ubuntu. For some reason, I'm getting completely different behavior when I use a temporary variable.
This version works fine:
void f2(const g_t *o, const g_t *n, int x, int y) {
    int m = f4(o, x, y);
    f3(n, x, y, m == 3 ? f1 : f2);
}

If I inline the call to f4, it stops working correctly and always returns 0.
void f2(const g_t *o, const g_t *n, int x, int y) {
    f3(n, x, y, f4(o, x, y) == 3 ? f1 : f2);
}

Not that it should matter, but here are the prototypes of the functions:
void f1(const g_t *o, const g_t *n, int x, int y);
void f2(const g_t *o, const g_t *n, int x, int y);
void f3(const g_t *g, int x, int y, s_t s);
int f4(const g_t *g, int x, int y);

I even tried compiling without optimizations just to be sure.
The gcc flags are: -g -m32 -std=c17 -O0
None of these functions make any changes to anything in the program, including any global state (again - not that it should make a difference). There are also no macros defined.
Any clue?

Can you describe what these "completely different behavior"s are?  Or at least what the differences are?

Post a [mcve]. The code might be invoking undefined behavior, but we can't tell without seeing it.

Agreed that a [mcve] is needed.  There's very likely something wrong within the body of a function that you haven't shown us.

Very very often, when someone omits part of their code because "it doesn't make any difference", they are mistaken, and the part they omitted is exactly what makes the difference.  So always, show it all.

I'll try to make an MRE and update the post.

@NateEldredge Or rather, make a minimal reproducible example, and then show the full example. Showing the entire program is (usually) almost as useless because it's too much code for people to want to sift through. Half the time, you accidentally find the problem while making the MRE and then you don't even need to ask the question.
